# How can I get my Heroku database insert privileges back after exceeding the basic plan limit, but then deleting all the rows to rectify?

Tags: heroku

I recently left an app languish and rack up too many rows, so Heroku revoked my database privileges:

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for relation
```

I cleared out all the extraneous 16k rows.

How can I get Heroku to turn back on my database privileges?

This is just a prototype app I don't have money to pay for yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.teknoids.net/content/heroku-postgres-basic-plan

> Once the number of rows is again in compliance with the plan limit,
>   INSERT privileges are automatically restored to the database. Note
>   that the database sizes are checked asynchronously, so it may take a
>   few minutes for the privileges to be restored.

Comment: Yep. Been panic searching the answer, but turned out I just had to wait a few minutes. phew!